# pandas combining 2 dataframes with different date indices

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Let's say I've pulled csv data from two seperate files containing a date index that pandas automatically pulled which was one of the original columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(data1, parse_dates = True, infer_datetime_format=True, index_col=0, names=['A'])
df2 = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(data2, parse_dates = True, infer_datetime_format=True, index_col=0, names=['A'])
```

Now the dates for one csv file are different than the other, but when loaded with read_csv, the dates are well defined. I've tried the join command, but it doesn't seem to preserve the dates.

```
df1 = df1.join(df2)
```

I get a valid data frame, but the range of the dates is fixed to some smaller subset of what the original range should be given the disparity between the dates for the two csv files. What I would like is a way to create a single dataframe with 2 columns (both 'A' columns) that contains NaN or zero values for the non overlapping dates filled in automatically. Is there a simple solution for this or is there something that I might be missing here. Thanks so much.

Comment: What you want is called outer join and is controlled with `how` argument, see [in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, pandas DataFrame method 'join' combines two dataframes using 'inner' merging. You want to use 'outer' merging. Your join line should read:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html